# What is the minimum value of y?

Tags: calculus

$$y=\sqrt{250000+(1000-x)^2}+\sqrt{90000 + x^2}$$

In this expression, what is the minimum value of $y$ and what is the $x$ value at this point? How do you work this out? Thank you in advance for your help.

I think to find the $x$ value I have to solve:

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+90000}} - \frac{1000-x}{\sqrt{(1000-x)^2+250000}}=0$

Am I right? How do I solve this?

Comment: Seems min is about 1280 when x is about 375. The derivative is a mess to set it equal to zero as in usual method...

Comment: Is there a way you can work it out without plotting a graph?

Comment: I don't know why @Amzoti would have you plot the function, when you have the critical points and the value at those, all you need is to know what happens at the ends of the domain, you don't need a plot for that.

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a stupid question. How do you find the critical points?

Comment: A critical pont of a function is a point where it's derivative is $0$.

Comment: @Amzoti: I am trying to review them now. I am very new to calculus so I am having some difficulty at the moment.

Comment: I understand how you can find critical points with a graph. How do you find critical points with algebra only? Is it possible? How would you find them for this? Thank you

Comment: @Amzoti's latest comment tells you how to find the critial points, the graph doesn't matter for that.

Comment: @Matt You have to take the derivative to find the critical points, then use the First Derivative Test to determine whether those critical points are maxima or minima.  To get additional help with this problem, take the derivative, set it equal to 0, and edit your question to show your work.

Answer (score 2):

Put $x:=1000 t$. Then it's about the function
$$f(t):=1000\left(\sqrt{(t-1)^2+0.25}+\sqrt{t^2+0.09}\right)\ .$$
This function can be interpreted as
$$f(t)=1000\bigl(|AX_t|+|X_tB|\bigr)$$
with $A:=(1,-0.5)\,$, $\>B:=(0,0.3)\,$, and $X_t:=(t,0)$. It is obvious that we obtain the minimum of $f$ when we connect $A$ and $B$ with a line $\ell$.

Therefore the minimum value of your $y$ is $1000|AB|=200\sqrt{41}$.